# How to Extract Date Out of a String Variable that is not in Date Format?

Tags: string, sorting, stata, date-conversion

I want to extract the date out of a string variable. But the string variable looks nothing like a conventional date format.

My data set looks like this:

```
v1    date
234   nominal_price_2010
545   nominal_price_2011
23    nominal_price_2012
934   nominal_price_2013
```

What I want to get :

```
v1    date
234   2010
545   2011
23    2012
934   2013
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
destring date, ignore("nomial_prce") replace
```

Solution 2:

```
gen work = real(substr(date, -4, 4)) 
drop date 
rename work date
```